# "We offer" vs. "we are offering" in context

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Can you please tell me if I need to say *we offer* or *we are offering* in the context below?

> We are clearly at fault in this situation, so **we offer** you a 100 dollar discount.
>
> We are clearly at fault in this situation, so **we are offering** you a 100 dollar discount.

Generally I'm aware of when to use the present simple or the present continuous, but in this context I'm not sure. Sometimes people say "I give you my word," not "I'm giving you my word." Or "I propose a toast," not "I'm proposing a toast", so I'm confused.

Would you please tell me which one is correct here and tell me the logic behind using one and not the other?

Comment: The usual rules apply. What are you confused about?

Comment: @gotube: Sometimes people say "I give you my word," not "I'm giving you my word." Or "I propose a toast," not "I'm proposing a toast." So I when you said that usual rules apply, would you please be more specific and tell me which one is correct there?

Comment: Gotcha. I've added this info to the question as it really clarifies what you're after.

Comment: The continuous one sounds more natural to me but I would hesitate to say the present simple was wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two expressions "I give you my word" and "I propose a toast" are idiomatic expressions that don't follow modern grammar rules for present simple. Or at least, the function of "*declare what you are doing as the act of doing it*" for present simple is constrained to only a few contexts, including the two you give. There are other contexts where it applies, like "I name/dub/christen..." and so on.

It does not apply to "offer" in that way. If you use it in that sense, it will sound either like a mistake, or like you're imitating English from hundreds of years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as an exchange or business.

> I give you my word,
>
> I propose a toast.

The other party does not need to do anything. Business concluded. You can use 'simple present'.

> We are offering you.

Business is not concluded. It is yet to be concluded. You can use 'present continuous'.

> We offer you.

Business concluded. You can use 'simple present'.

Both sentences are correct.

> XYZ airlines: We offer you unmatched comfort.
>
> XYZ airlines: We are offering you unmatched comfort.